# How to deploy i18n Angular app to Netlify?

Tags: angular, internationalization, netlify

I'm trying to deploy my i18n Angular app to [netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) but I don't know exactly how.

When I run the command `ng build --prod --localize` I get two sub-directories: `dist/app-name/en-US` and `dist/app-name/es`

I need to access these sub-folders as follows:

```
(English) https://example.netlify.app
(Spanish) https://example.netlify.app/es
```

These are my deploy settings:

```
Base directory: Not set
Build command: ng build --prod --build-optimizer --aot --localize
Publish directory: dist/app-name
```

I have the `_redirects` file with the following content.

```
/*  /index.html 200
```

I suppose I need to edit this file to redirect to each sub-directory.

I'd appreciate it if you could guide me through.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect solution, but this working:

`src/_redirects`

```
/en/*    /en/index.html   200
/es/*    /es/index.html   200
```

Another more generic and cleaner possibility

```
/:lang/*    /:lang/index.html   200
```

in `package.json` change your `build` script to and add `netlify` script:

```
"build": "ng build && npm run netlify",
"netlify": "cp src/_redirects dist/{YOUR-PROJECT-NAME}/_redirects"
```